# Zooming out a hybrid webapp for a webview to match the screen width and height maintaining the aspect ratio

Tags: android, html, css, webview

I have to turn a website originally developed for 1920 x 1080 resolution **with the requirement of having no scrolling**, to a hybrid android app for an android device that supports 1024x768 resolution with **no scroll bars.**. The whole website is wired using definite pixel values, with widths, heights and offsets specified in pixels, with thousands of pixel definitions in css. Is there a workaround to do it without manually calculating every element's definitive position and specifying in the css files? the original site wasn't developed using any of scss, and the target platform is android webview. The meta tags do not seem to work in my case.

This is to be used in a internal setting only, developing this from bottom up is a bad idea, since I have to reuse the existing code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

css 2d transform, scale applied on body element resolved the issue, but make sure it is prefixed with -webkit- in order to work on android

```
body{
            -webkit-transform: scale(0.67,0.645);
            -webkit-transform-origin: left top;
    }
```

Comment: please give a more elaborate answer, optimally with the code, so it can be more useful to others with the same issue.